# MongoDb.js / Mongoose find() translate a String in ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, objectid

I have two schemas utilizing Mongoose

**Schema 1**

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
return mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

**Schema 2**

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    }
});
return mongoose.model('Page', schema);
```

**My Data in Page Collection**

_id
551b0cdf63dc96e9c39de0f8
551b0d1563dc96e9c39de0f9
551b0d2d63dc96e9c39de0fa
551b0d4363dc96e9c39de0fb
551daae0f4cb312c62dcbc1e

name
Cazaquistao
Russia
China
Australia
El Salvador

user
5515c7aaaf6d59fea26d7185
5515c7aaaf6d59fea26d7185
5515c7aaaf6d59fea26d7185
5515c7aaaf6d59fea26d7185
5515c7c9af6d59fea26d7186

when i search in schema 2 by user, I dont find any results.

The mongoose translate the mongoose converts the query erroneously.

**Query**

```
var test = Page.find().select("_id").where({"user" : "5515c7aaaf6d59fea26d7185"}).exec()                  
 .then(function (t) {                
   console.log("hi", t);                
   });
```

**Query Translated erroneously**

```
db.pages.find({ user: ObjectId("5515c7aaaf6d59fea26d7185") })
```

*no results*

**Query as it should be**

```
db.pages.find({ user: "5515c7aaaf6d59fea26d7185" })=
```

*4 results*

Any suggestions of what to do to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

If `user` is a string in your page docs, then your schema needs to reflect that or Mongoose will try and cast it to the type in your schema (`ObjectId` in this case).

So make `user` a string in the schema:

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    user: {
        type: String,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    }
});
```

Comment: No, user doesnt a string object, but i think i know  what  is happening. The collection was created wrong.

Comment: Ok.  Probably best to just delete the question then.

Answer (score -1):

I solved passing a objectId rather than a String